# Timestamp comparison with python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to do a timestamp comparison with mysql.connector in Python3.
For some reason I've got an empty result with the following query:

```
SELECT timestamp, reading, value FROM history where device='dht22' and timestamp > now() - interval 6 hour
```

If I switch the operator to "<" the query works and shows all the results, older than 6 hours ago, but it's not what I want. I want to show the results from the past 6 hours only.

If I execute the query directly in mysql, it works as expected, but in python it doesn't. How can I go around this?

My current python code is like so:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='db')
cur = cnx.cursor()

query="SELECT `timestamp`, `reading`, `value` FROM history where device='dht22' and `timestamp` > now() - interval 6 hour"

cur.execute(query)

rows=cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

cur.close()
cnx.close()
```

**[UPDATE]** I found the problem. I was connecting to the MySQL server though "localhost" and for some reason (bad configuration probably), it was not parsing timestamp comparison correctly. When I put the full domain name in the connection object, all works fine. Really weird!

Answer (score 0):

use BETWEEN

```
SELECT `timestamp`, reading, value FROM history WHERE device='dht22' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 6 hour AND NOW()
```

> ```
> create table history(
>  id int primary key,
>   reading int, 
>   value varchar(19),
>   device  VARCHAR(10),
>   `timestamp` datetime
>   );
>   
> INSERT INTO history VALUES (1,1,'test','dht22', NOW() - INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
> ,(2,1,'test','dht22', NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
> ,(3,1,'test','dht22', NOW() - INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `timestamp`, reading, value 
> FROM history 
> WHERE device='dht22' AND `timestamp` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 6 hour AND NOW()
> ```
>
> ```
> timestamp           | reading | value
> :------------------ | ------: | :----
> 2020-08-23 14:30:04 |       1 | test 
> 2020-08-23 17:30:04 |       1 | test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d3c8c42900c138ceca5a12607eac7d7)*

See [image]

And also my select

[image: see python]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the same empty result. I tried also with python's timedelta and using %s in the query, but the result is still empty.

Comment: I added an example to show that it works. Please add you own fiddle to show where the problem is

Comment: Yes, the query works directly in mysql, but not in the python script. I've edit my question with the script code.

Comment: i added a picture to show you that it works in python without a problem

Comment: That is really strange. Do you have any idea where should I look for the problem?  My mysql-connector module version is 2.2.9.

Comment: i checked everything is uptodate, try to update python and the pip packages and see if you have still a problem, also add a try and ECEPT and see if you git an mysql error or any other kind

Comment: Ok, I think I'll be stuck with this. It seems my hosting's mysql version is an old one (5.1), which according to the mysql-connector version page was reported to work with 5.1, but was not officially supported. O the top of that my pip lists only version 2.29 of the connector, so I can't even try the old one (1.2). Thanks you for you help!